# Remove last n characters from -print0?

Tags: text-processing, string

Currently I have:

`@find . -type f -name "img*_01.png" -print0 | python script.py -f {}`

is there a way to trim the last few chars like this?

`@find . -type f -name "img*_01.png" -print0 | python script.py -f {}.rightTrim(n)`

Comment: Where do you enter that command line? Shouldn't there be a `xargs -r0I {}` somewhere in there?

Comment: With (recent versions of) GNU `sed`, you can pipe the `find -print0` output to `sed -Ez 's/.{5}$//'`

Comment: Or with GNU `awk` or recent versions of `mawk`: `awk -v RS='\0' -v ORS='\0' '{print substr($0,1,length-5)}'`

Comment: Removing 5 characters would remove `1.png`. Are you sure that's what you mean?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas sorry, yeah xargs should be in there. I'll rename the question to remove n characters.

Comment: Why you can't do it inside of `script.py`?

Comment: I could but then I wouldn't learn how to do it on the command line. I don't want to dirty up my script as this is an edge case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you meant:

```
find . -type f -name "img*_01.png" -print0 |
  xargs -r0I{} python script.py -f {}
```

That can't be done with `xargs`, as in `xargs` has no *rightTrim()* operator. You can either do away with `xargs` and do something like (`bash`, `zsh` syntax):

```
find . -type f -name "img*_01.png" -print0 |
  while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
    python script.py -f "${file%?????}"
  done
```

Or keep `xargs` but invoke a shell to do the trimming:

```
find . -type f -name "img*_01.png" -print0 | xargs -r0 sh -c '
  for file do
    python script.py -f "${file%?????}"
  done' sh
```

Though in that case, you might as well use the standard `-exec {} +` syntax:

```
find . -type f -name "img*_01.png" -exec sh -c
  for file do
    python script.py -f "${file%?????}"
  done' sh {} +
```

Or (if you don't otherwise also need the full filename), pipe the output to some command that trims the last 5 characters of each filename:

```
sed -zE 's/.{5}$//' # assuming recent GNU sed
```

or

```
awk -v RS='\0' -v ORS='\0' '{print substr($0,1,length-5)}'
```

(assuming GNU `awk` or recent versions of `mawk`).

On GNU systems, you can also do it with basic one-task utilities with:

```
tr '\n\0' '\0\n' | rev | cut -c 6- | rev | tr '\n\0' '\0\n'
```

And there's always `perl`:

```
perl -0 -pe 's/.{5}$//'
perl -0 -lpe 'chop;chop;chop;chop;chop'
perl -0 -lpe 'substr($_,-5,5,"")'
```

Comment: For **sed** without `-z` option `... -print0 | sed 's/.....\x0/\x0/g' | xargs -0 ...`